# Handle a client component from a server during an AJAX request

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, ajax4jsf

In my application, i have implemented a message bar for displaying info and error message, which will close when a screen navigation occurs(a javascript function triggered by **window.onunload** event).

In few places, i have implemented **a4j:commandButton** to render a specific modalpanel, without a screen refresh. In such case, existing message bar stays(since there is no screen refresh!!!), new message bar gets appended to it.

I very well knew about the implementation of **a4j:commandButton**'s attribute "**onClick()**". It may be hectic to implement it in all the existing buttons. I want a one time implementation at server side (if possible at PhaseListener), so that i need not write any onunload javascript function or an **onClick()** functionality.

Can anyone give me a brief idea on how to control the message bar from server side in ajax scenario.?

Thanks in advance.!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you asked a server side solution but there is a relatively easy client side solution to this problem which I think you might prefer.

if you want to add a function to all or some of the button elements  on "onClick" you could try using the following code.

replace   with your function to be added on the click event.
replace   with the name of your form (you can pass is as a parameter)

btw, this code **supports IE FF CHROME** etc.

```
function addFunctionToAllButtons()
{
    var buttons = document.*YourForm*.getElementsByTagName("button"); 
    for(i=0; i<buttons.length; i++)
    {
        if(buttons[i].id =='yourButtonId')
        {
        attachEvent(buttons[i],'click',*yourFunction*,false);
        }
    }

}


function attachEvent(obj,evt,fnc,useCapture)
{
    if (!useCapture) useCapture=false;
    if (obj.addEventListener)
    {
        obj.addEventListener(evt,fnc,useCapture);
        return true;
    }
    else if (obj.attachEvent) 
        return obj.attachEvent("on"+evt,fnc);
    else
    {
        MyAttachEvent(obj,evt,fnc);
        obj['on'+evt]=function(){ MyFireEvent(obj,evt) };
    }
}
```

-- Edit

to suuport child pages we need to take special notice to  the buuton id we refer to in the following line:

```
if(buttons[i].id =='yourButtonId')
```

and to the form Id

hope this helps.

Comment: seems to be a better client side implementation.! can this be implemented in the parent page, so that the child pages can inherit it?

Comment: @radKrish It can be implemented in child pages. edited answer